# Why EnvDTE.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel is Null on Dynamics 365 in VS 2017 project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, x++, vsix, envdte, dynamics-365-operations

I am writing code to get the CodeElements from .xpp file  in D365 project, but FileCodeModel value is always null

```
foreach (Project project in applicationObject.Solution.Projects)
 {
                        var projectItems = GetProjectItemsRecursively(project.ProjectItems);
                        foreach (ProjectItem item in projectItems)
                        {
                            if ((item.FileCodeModel != null))
                            {
                                
                                foreach (CodeElement elem in item.FileCodeModel.CodeElements)
                                {
                                    
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for [ProjectItem.FileCodeModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.projectitem.filecodemodel?view=visualstudiosdk-2017), "A FileCodeModel object is returned only for project items that are code files and in projects that implement the Visual Studio code model."

Since [x++](/questions/tagged/x%2b%2b) is a very distant cousin of the .NET family, my guess would be that its files (.xml files that combine code and metadata) are not recognized as code files and/or the D365FO projects do not implement the VS code model.